# Tips for installing multiple blockchain nodes?

Tags: blockchain, nodes, polygon, bsc

we are developing a product that requires connection to several blockchain nodes. Our customers decided to assemble their hardware to install a full node on it. In this connection, we have a question about the characteristics of the assembled machine. Specifically, full nodes of Bitcoin, Ethereum, BSC and Polygon are required. If I just add up the required ssd characteristics for these nodes, choose a sufficiently powerful processor with many cores and 32GB of RAM, will this be enough for me to maintain the operation of 4 such nodes? Perhaps you can advise something?